# caffe what is SetLossWeights?

Tags: caffe

I am reading caffe's Layer source code but I got following questions:

1. What is `Layer::SetLossWeights` function doing? I know that inside Layer class, there is a `loss_` variable, which documents:

> The vector that indicates whether each top blob has a non-zero weight
>   in the objective function.

Do they have some relationships ?

2. Inside the caffe.proto file, LayerParameter loss_weight is only for loss layers, is that correct?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The purpose of loss weight is to combine loss from multiple layers. So `Layer::SetLossWeights` is assigning the loss weight to `loss_` variable and `diff blob` which is used in `forward` to compute total loss.
2. As default layers with suffix loss have loss weight 1 and others with 0. But any layer that is able to backpropagate can be given a non-zero loss_weight.

For detail information see [caffe loss tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/loss.html).

Edit:

`Loss weight` will only change if it is input to another layer that does backprop which is not intended by the authors. As they said for `Accuracy layer` in this [pull request](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/686) it will break. The purpose of the `diff` in `loss layer` is to store `loss weight` not store gradient. For more detail you can see this discussion in [caffe-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/0olIEavx88M).

Comment: One thing I'm not clear is that by storing `loss_weight` in top blob's `diff` variable, it is assumed that the `loss_weight` will change over time. Because apparently, after performing backpropagation, top blob's `diff`changed. Is that right?

Comment: @Johnnylin if you have loss layers at the end only then it is not changing (see loss code). Otherwise it will change.

Comment: If it is a loss layer, the `loss_weight` still will change overtime. Loss layer needs to compute diff and store in the diff array. ?