# How to write a solver.prototxt satisfy a given condition in CAFFE?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am writing the solver.prototxt that follows the rule of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02677.pdf

> In the training phase, the learning rate was set as 0.001 initially and decreased by a factor of 10 when the loss stopped decreasing till 10−7. The discount weight was set as 1 initially and decreased by a factor of 10 every ten thousand iterations until a marginal value 10−3.

Note that, the discount weight is loss_weight in Caffe. Based on the information above, I wrote my solver as

```
train_net: "train.prototxt"
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 10000
base_lr: 0.001 #0.002
```

In train.prototxt, I also set

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "deconv"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_weight: 1
}
```

However, I still don't know how to set solver to satisfy the rule **"decreased by a factor of 10 when the loss stopped decreasing till 10−7"** and **"decreased by a factor of 10 every ten thousand iterations until a marginal value 10−3"**. I did not found any caffe rule can do it as the reference:

```
// The learning rate decay policy. The currently implemented learning rate
// policies are as follows:
//    - fixed: always return base_lr.
//    - step: return base_lr * gamma ^ (floor(iter / step))
//    - exp: return base_lr * gamma ^ iter
//    - inv: return base_lr * (1 + gamma * iter) ^ (- power)
//    - multistep: similar to step but it allows non uniform steps defined by
//      stepvalue
//    - poly: the effective learning rate follows a polynomial decay, to be
//      zero by the max_iter. return base_lr (1 - iter/max_iter) ^ (power)
//    - sigmoid: the effective learning rate follows a sigmod decay
//      return base_lr ( 1/(1 + exp(-gamma * (iter - stepsize))))
//
// where base_lr, max_iter, gamma, step, stepvalue and power are defined
// in the solver parameter protocol buffer, and iter is the current iteration.
```

If anyone knows it, please give me some guide to writing the solver.prototxt to satisfy above condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Learning rate reduction**

Part of the problem is that the phrase `decreased by a factor of 10 when the loss stopped decreasing till 10e−7` does not quite make sense.  I think that, perhaps, the authors are trying to say that every time the loss quit decreasing, they reduced the learning rate by a factor of 10, until the learning rate got to 10e-7.

If so, then this is a manual process, not something you can choose with Caffe parameters.  Most of all, "when the loss stopped decreasing" is a non-trivial judgement, although a long-base moving average will give you a good indication.  I expect that the authors did this manually, stopping and restarting the training from a checkpoint.

You *can* get a similar effect with a learning rate decay policy of `step`: set gamma to 0.1, and set the step parameter high enough to ensure that training has levelled off before each rate reduction.  This will waste some computer time, but might save you overall trouble.

**Discount weight**

In Caffe, the loss weight is merely the relative weighting among the various losses in the model, linear factors used to achieve the final loss statistic.  Caffe does not provide run-time alteration of the weight.  Perhaps this was something else that the authors tuned by hand.

I tried reading the areas of the paper around the two references to "discount weight", but found it hard reading.  I'll wait until someone proofreads and edits that paper for grammar and clarity.  In the meantime, I hope this answer helps you some.

You can find a little more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094891/caffe-what-is-setlossweights).

Comment: Thanks Prune. It is helpful. You also can look at the other paper of the author about `discount weight` that he also used it in the http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811917303348

Comment: I see; thanks for the reference.  The English is somewhat better in this one.  Those weights are not something you can dynamically tune from `solver.prototxt`.  However, if you would like to enhance the code and propose it to BVLC, I'm sure they would give your added functionality good consideration.

Comment: One more thing, you said we can adjust the weight manually during training. How can we do it? Because we can only save the solverstate and caffemodel files after each snapshot.

Comment: Right.  You run for 10000 iterations, take a snapshot, and halt training.  Change solver.prototxt and restart from that snapshot.  In short, it's a tedious fine-tuning process.